# access web sql database between 2 html5 pages

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html5 and js,if this is a very simple question, please forgive my ignorance.
But can someone please help me in figuring a solution for my case:

I have created some static html5 pages and also a offline database from my js code which is accessed across all the html5 pages.
Now i am trying to update the database from one page and want the **updated database reflection across all the html5 pages**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you said it is offline db, store the values in some global variable before storing it in database. And in all other pages , rely on that global variable.So , if you have some data updated in page1, store it in some global variable also. And use that variable in all other pages.

Comment: For offline db i meant is i have no server communication and i have inserted static dummy values into the fields of the db table.And now when i updated the values in the table the updated database table should reflect on all the other pages that are accessing it.

Answer (score 0):

To access the offline databases from several different pages, please make sure all your pages are in the same domain.

Create a **fresh connection** to the database on all your pages.

```
var db_conn = window.openDatabase( _ID_DATABASE_NAME, _ID_DATABASE_VERSION, _ID_DATABASE_DESC, _ID_DATABASE_SIZE );
```

All the parameters passed to the function should remain same.

In case the values you are trying to access are only a few name value pairs, try to use the concept of **local storages**. Following are the setter getter methods accessible across pages.

```
window.localStorage.setItem( 'myFirstLocalStorage_Name', 'myFirstLocalStorage_Value' );
var ls_value = window.localStorage.getItem( 'myFirstLocalStorage_Name' );
```

Hope you'll be able to get your values across pages.

Answer (score 0):

The domain of both pages is needed to be same.

and w3c  says

> User agents may restrict access to the database objects to scripts
>   originating at the domain of the top-level document of the browsing
>   context, for instance denying access to the API for pages from other
>   domains running in iframes.