# WebSql transfer data to another webpage

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I want to return the same data from my WebSql database into another webpage `test.html`. But I currently do not know how to achieve that. I have also read this post on how to [access web sql database between 2 html5 pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118497/access-web-sql-database-between-2-html5-pages), but I dont really understand what I am supposed to do.

This is my code so far:

```
<h1>WebSQL Example</h1>
<form action="test.html">
<div id="controls">
    <p>Add a car to the database</p>
    <label>Make:</label>
    <input type="text" id="carmake" />
    <br />
    <label>Model:</label>
    <input type="text" id="carmodel" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="text" />
    <button type="button" id="addcar" onclick="addCar();">Add Car</button>
</div>
</form>
<div id="carlistholder">
     <h3>Your Cars</h3>

    <ul id="carlist"></ul>
</div>
<script>
//Test for browser compatibility
if (window.openDatabase) {
    //Create the database the parameters are 1. the database name 2.version number 3. a description 4. the size of the database (in bytes) 1024 x 1024 = 1MB
    var mydb = openDatabase("cars_db", "0.1", "A Database of Cars I Like", 1024 * 1024);

    //create the cars table using SQL for the database using a transaction
    mydb.transaction(function (t) {
        t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS help (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, make TEXT, model TEXT, text TEXT)");
    });



} else {
    alert("WebSQL is not supported by your browser!");
}

//function to output the list of cars in the database

function updateCarList(transaction, results) {
    //initialise the listitems variable
    var listitems = "";
    //get the car list holder ul
    var listholder = document.getElementById("carlist");

    //clear cars list ul
    listholder.innerHTML = "";

    var i;
    //Iterate through the results
    for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        //Get the current row
        var row = results.rows.item(i);

        listholder.innerHTML += "<li>" + row.make + " - " + row.model + " - " + row.text + " (<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteCar(" + row.id + ");'>Delete Car</a>)";
    }

}

//function to get the list of cars from the database

function outputCars() {
    //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
    if (mydb) {
        //Get all the cars from the database with a select statement, set outputCarList as the callback function for the executeSql command
        mydb.transaction(function (t) {
            t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM test", [], updateCarList);
        });
    } else {
        alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
    }
}

//function to add the car to the database

function addCar() {
    //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
    if (mydb) {
        //get the values of the make and model text inputs
        var make = document.getElementById("carmake").value;
        var model = document.getElementById("carmodel").value;
        var text = document.getElementById("text").value;

        //Test to ensure that the user has entered both a make and model
        if (make !== "" && model !== "") {
            //Insert the user entered details into the cars table, note the use of the ? placeholder, these will replaced by the data passed in as an array as the second parameter
            mydb.transaction(function (t) {
                t.executeSql("INSERT INTO test (make, model, text) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [make, model, text]);
            });
        } else {
            alert("You must enter a make and model!");
        }
    } else {
        alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
    }
}


//function to remove a car from the database, passed the row id as it's only parameter

function deleteCar(id) {
    //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
    if (mydb) {
        //Get all the cars from the database with a select statement, set outputCarList as the callback function for the executeSql command
        mydb.transaction(function (t) {
            t.executeSql("DELETE FROM test WHERE id=?", [id], outputCars);
        });
    } else {
        alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
    }
}

outputCars();
</script>
<p><strong>Note: </strong>You can leave this page and when you return the cars you entered will still be here!</p>
```

Comment: Not to be a show stopper, but are you trying to use the [Web SQL Database](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)? This spec is not maintained anymore. I would suggest that you use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) instead. This is in active development and is supported by all. So, in either case you should be able to access the same database from different HTML files just by referring to the same database -- in you case openDatabase("cars_db"...). Try copying the HTML file that works -- you can access the same data in both, cant you?

Comment: Yea I am using Web SQL Database, but I currently do not know how to use IndexedDB.

Comment: Is there also a site with more information on how to access the same data in another html webpage

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you meaning two HTML files (in the same directory and same domain) or from two different websites with different domains (like example.com and example.org)?

Comment: two html in same directory